# Hide/Show parameters based on a condition in Azure DevOps Pipelines YAML

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a use case where I have multiple parameters in ADO build pipeline but those parameters should be visible based on a condition e.g. the branch name (for releases/* branches). Following is a template to showcase what I am trying to achieve:

```
variables:
- name: systemAccessToken
  value: $(System.AccessToken)
- name: system.debug
  value: true
- ${{if startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/releases/') }}:
  - name: START_DATE_TIME
    value: ${{ parameters.startDateTime }}
  - name: END_DATE_TIME
    value: ${{ parameters.endDateTime }}

- ${{if startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/releases/') }}:
  parameters:
  - name: startDateTime
    displayName: Enter the Start Datetime
    type: string
    default: 04-14-2022 14:55:00
  - name: endDateTime
    displayName: Enter the End Datetime
    type: string
    default: 04-14-2022 23:00:00
    
resources:
  repositories:
  ...
  ...


stages:
  ...
  ...
```

The above doesn't work but I would like to get an idea if there is some way I can achieve this using any workaround like injecting the parameters at runtime. Would appreciate any help on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, can't be done. The list of parameters is fixed and the pipeline is compiled, before it ever knows about any runtime variables such as Build.SourceBranch.

Instead, you could perhaps define two different pipelines with different sets of parameters? You can avoid duplicating code by extracting the common elements (resources, variables, stages) into a template.

Comment: Ah too bad. Simple answer: can’t be done due to limitations of Azure