# How to have conditional parameters which depends on another parameter in YAML?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We use Azure DevOps for deploy things to Azure. If you know, How to build YAML such way that if we choose one parameter then depends on it, automatically another parameter should showup?

For example. In AzurePowershell task, before running pipeline, If we choose inline script then it will ask us to enter script but if we choose filepath then it will ask for path of the file. Refer below code for good example.

Could you please let me know how to achieve this in YAML?

```
parameters:
  - name: is_okay
    type: boolean
    displayName: Are you Okay?
    default: True

  - name: plan
    type: string  
    displayName: Let's go for outing
    default: 'Plan for Africa tour'
    condition: eq(parameters.is_okay, true)
```

Only if is_okay true then Plan will showup. If is_okay is false then it plan parameter should not showup. I tried something above, but didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide/Show parameters based on a condition in Azure DevOps Pipelines YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72185081/hide-show-parameters-based-on-a-condition-in-azure-devops-pipelines-yaml)

Comment: Hi Manish, Thanks for checking for me. In fact, I've tried it but it only works for variables not for parameters. Seems we have no options  but can expect this feature in further.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this.

In tasks you can achieve this using a `visibleRule`, but that concept doesn't exist for parameters.

Comment: Oh, Okay. Hope we can see this feature in future. Thank you very much Jesse : )

Comment: but how about my above AzurePowershell task giving those features? Is it because that's a classic pipeline?

Comment: That's a task. Tasks are different from parameters. A task has a task manifest and inputs can define a `visibleRule`. This concept isn't universally applied to all places that generate a UI to input data across Azure Pipelines. https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/blob/4086d6bef172fe1329d3006ccacc324e05baac1e/tasks.schema.json#L222-L225