# Conditional Display of Azure DevOps Pipeline Parameters Based on Other Parameter Values

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Using Azure DevOps, in the pipeline definition, how can I conditionally display a parameter depending on another parameter?

Example:

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: whatever
    displayName: "Choose a value"
    type: string
    values:
      - abc
      - def
  
  - name: hiddenUnlessDEF
    displayName: "Choose a second value"
    type: string
    values:
      - whatever
      - what
    dependsOn: whatever
    condition: eq('${{ parameters.whatever }}', 'def')
```

However, when I try this, Azure returns an error: 'dependsOn' is an unexpected value.

Comment: The dependsOn property is not supported in Azure DevOps pipeline parameters. To conditionally display a parameter depending on another parameter, you can use a template expression.

Comment: possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72185081/hide-show-parameters-based-on-a-condition-in-azure-devops-pipelines-yaml

Answer (score -1):

Checking the [pipeline.parameters.parameter definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/parameters-parameter?view=azure-pipelines), we can see that the `dependsOn` and `condition` are not supported in parameters properties.

Comment: Please re read the question. Not the answer I’m looking for.

Comment: OK I understand your question, however the answer you are looking for seems to be "not supported". Maybe you could share why you need to do this in order to find a more suitable workaround.

Comment: If it is not supported, then that is the answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I will edit to delete the workaround. Thanks.